# Getting value from one include in a makefile in another

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

My project have a lot of modules and i want to do some partial building depending on a configured value. So i was testing the same with the following sameple

config.mk

```
    somevar := apple
    export somevar
```

rules.mk

```
    ifeq ( $(somevar), apple)
    export someother := banana
    else
    export someother := tomato
    endif
```

makefile

```
    include config.mk
    include rules.mk

    all:
        @echo $(somevar)
        @echo $(someother)
```

This prints

```
    apple
    tomato
```

but i want "apple banana ". Please help me identify the error.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the whitespace in your ifeq.  It's evaluating to false due to extra whitespace:

```
ifeq ($(somevar),apple)
```

will work.